# Show that a sequence is monotonically increasing.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

It's given that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a > 0$ and $0<x_1<\frac{1}{a}$. The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined by $x_{n+1} = 2x_n-ax^2_n.$ Now, I first proved by induction that $x_n < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then I was wondering, if it is enough to just show that $x_{n+1} = 2x_n-ax^2_n > 2x_n - \frac{1}{x_n}x^2_n = 2x_n-x_n = x_n$ to fully prove that $ x_{n+1} > x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and therefore $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically increasing? Thanks for any corrections or tips, I'm just not sure if I might be missing something.

Comment: Yes, it would  be enough, but how do you prove it?

Comment: How do you know that $\frac1{x_n}\gt a$?

Comment: 1.: $x_1 < \frac{1}{a}$ by Definition. 
2.: Let's suppose that $x_n < \frac{1}{a}$ is true. Then $x_{n+1} < \frac{1}{a}$ should follow.
3.: $x_{n+1} = 2x_n-ax^2_n = x_n(2-ax_n) <  \frac{1}{a}(2-\frac{1}{a}a) = \frac{1}{a}.$

Comment: I don't think your induction step works out, because the second $x_n$ is replaced by the _bigger_  $\frac1a$, and then _subtracted_.

Comment: Your proof is OK but you have to justify the inequality $x_n(2-ax_n) <\frac 1 a (2-\frac 1 a a)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you have any tip for how I could do that, I just thought about it and verified by examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to justify the inequality $x_n(2-ax_n) <\frac 1 a (2-\frac 1 a a)$. To prove this consider the  function $f(t)=t(2-at)$ defined on $(0,\frac 1 a)$. Since $f'(t)=2-2at>0$ for all $t$ in the domain of $f$ this function is increasing. Since $t(2-at)=\frac 1 a$ when $t=\frac 1 a$ it follows (by looking at the extension of $f$ to $(0,\frac 1 a]$) that $f(t) <\frac 1 a$ for all $t$. So if we assume that $x_n <\frac 1 a$ we can take $t=x_n$ to see that $x_{n+1}<\frac  1 a$.

Comment: Thanks, that made it so clear. Now can I also ask you, if I want to show that my sequence converges to $\frac{1}{a}$, can I make my proof by showing that $lim_{n\to\infty} (x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{a})=0$?

Comment: The sequence is increasing and bounded above by $\frac 1 a$. This implies that it is convergent. If you call the limit $l$ then the given equation gives $l=2l-al^{2}$ or $l=al^{2}$. This means $l=0$ or $l =\frac 1 a$. Since $x_n >0$ (proved again by induction) for all $n$ and $x_n$ is increasing its limit cannot be $0$. Hence $l =\frac 1 a$.

Comment: Thanks, but which equations gives $l=2l-al^2$ or $al^2$? And what about the proof that I proposed? Is it sufficient? Because it works out since $lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{a})$ is equal to zero.

Comment: How do you show that $x_{n+1}-\frac 1 a \to 0$?

Comment: I'm sorry, just noticed I was mistaken. But could you still explain why these two equations give me l?

Comment: I am just taking limit as $ n \to \infty$ in the equation $x_{n+1}=2x_n-ax_n^{2}$. This gives $l=2l-al^{2}$. We can re-write this equation as $al^{2}=l$. This gives $l(al-1)=0$. So either $l=0$ or $al=1$. Once you rule out $l=0$ we are left with $al=1$ which gives $l=\frac 1 a$.

Comment: Awesome proof. Thank you very much.